# How to remove text in an element but show its children

Tags: html, css

I'm currently making a custom website CSS but came across a problem which I couldn't anywhere find online. I'm trying to remove the value of a `span` but showing the elements inside of it, in this case `a`.
The desired result in the examples would be the words `Foo!` & `Bar!` without the `-`.

```
<style>
    span
    {display: none;}
    span a
    {display: block}
</style>

<span>
    - <a href="#">Foo!</a>
    - <a href="#">Bar!</a>
</span>
```

This doesn't work, rather obvious but showing my attempts anyway, (It will remove everything).

```
<style>
    span:not(a)
    {display: none;}
</style>

<span>
    - <a href="#">Foo!</a>
    - <a href="#">Bar!</a>
</span>
```

My second attempt, also doesn't work but I couldn't think of much more. (Also removes everything).
Removing the `a` is not an problem but the other way around seems difficult. Am I either stupid or trying something impossible?

It's build for `Firefox` so any `Firefox` only solutions would be fine as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is:

```css
span {
  font-size: 0;
}
span a {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<span>
    - <a href="#">Foo!</a>
    - <a href="#">Bar!</a>
</span>
```

Or, using `rem` (the 'root em') rather than `px`:

```css
span {
  font-size: 0;
}
span a {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<span>
    - <a href="#">Foo!</a>
    - <a href="#">Bar!</a>
</span>
```

Your solutions can't work because in the case of your first attempt:

```
span {
  display: none;
}
span a {
  display: block;
}
```

The child of an element that has the 'display' property set to 'none' cannot be shown. And, your second solution:

```
span:not(a) {
  display: none;
}
```

will match any `<span>` element, since no `<span>` can (ever, under any circumstances) be an `<a>` element.

If JavaScript is an option - it's not a requirement, merely an option - then the following would also work:

```
function removeSpanText(span) {
  // getting the childNodes of the <span>:
  var children = span.childNodes,
    // a counter to keep track of where we
    // are in the (following) while loop:
    count = 0,
    // the 'current' element upon which we'll
    // acting within said while loop:
    current = children[count];

  // while the live NodeList of the <span> element's
  // childNodes still contains a number of elements
  // AND the count variable is still less than that
  // number of elements (accidental infinite loops are
  // frustrating):
  while (children.length && count < children.length) {
    // if the current node has a nodeType of 3
    // and is therefore a textNode:
    if (current.nodeType === 3) {
      // we remove the current node:
      current.parentNode.removeChild(current);
    } else {
      // otherwise we increment the count variable:
      count++;
    }
    // and reset the current variable to
    // hold either the element at the current
    // count number (if we removed the Node) or
    // or to the incremented count number
    // (if the Node was not a textNode):
    current = children[count];
  }
}

// getting a reference to <span elements within the
// document:
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

// using Array.prototype.forEach(), with
// Function.prototype.call(), to iterate
// over that NodeList:
Array.prototype.forEach.call(spans, function(span) {
  // the name of the first argument (here: 'span') is
  // user-defined, but is always the current array-element
  // of the array over which we're iterating.

  // calling the function, passing the span variable
  // as the argument:
  removeSpanText(span);
});
```

```js
function removeSpanText(span) {
  var children = span.childNodes,
    count = 0,
    current = children[count];
  while (children.length && count < children.length) {
    if (current.nodeType === 3) {
      current.parentNode.removeChild(current);
    } else {
      count++;
    }
    current = children[count];
  }
}

var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(spans, function(span) {
  removeSpanText(span);
});
```

```html
<span>
    - <a href="#">Foo!</a>
    - <a href="#">Bar!</a>
</span>
```

Comment: Ah, Thanks a lot! It's been a while since I touched CSS.

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm glad to have been of help! :)

Comment: Eventually I couldn't manage with calling `span a`, I had to call `span a:nth-child(1n+1)` to even out the `-` characters. But I never thought about lowering the font-size.